# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined (action)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using React+Redux. I am getting an error:

[image: Error]

While debugging, data from the server came to the state, and the action was empty:

[image: action empty]

This is part of my code:

```
class ProfileContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        debugger
        axios.get('https://social-network.samuraijs.com/api/1.0/profile/3')
            .then(response => {
                this.props.setUserProfile(response.data)
            })
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setUserProfile })(ProfileContainer);
```

My reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    posts: [
        { id: 1, message: "Hey, how are you?", likesCount: 3 },
        { id: 2, message: "This is my first post", likesCount: 15 },
        { id: 3, message: "This is my first post", likesCount: 17 },
    ],
    newPostText: "",
    profile: null
};

const profileReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    debugger
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER_PROFILE:
            return { ...state, profile: action.profile };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
export const setUserProfile = (profile) => ({ type: SET_USER_PROFILE, profile })
```

Comment: show how your component is connected to store, please

Comment: export const setUserProfile = (profile) => ({ type: SET_USER_PROFILE, profile }) can u check here are u getting profile here

Comment: component communicates with store using HOC (connect) library (react-redux)

Answer (score 0):

Initiate a dispatch, pass the result to the dispatch() function:

```
export const setUserProfile = (profile) => (dispatch({ type: SET_USER_PROFILE, profile }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatch flow is wrong you have to do like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    setUserProfile: (profile) => dispatch({ type: SET_USER_PROFILE, profile }),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfileContainer);
```

Comment: Yes, this is true, but I do not understand why my syntax is not correct, because connect itself calls dispatch and I just pass an object with actionCreator